# Machine learning: use benchmark as a feature

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

The project I am doing is to predict surgery lengths. The benchmark I am trying to compare is to take the average of most recent 20 cases for the cases with the same ID.

What I tested is to use this benchmark as a feature together with some other features like surgeon name, surgery difficulty level, etc. I thought most likely it will outperform the benchmark since it has benchmark as a feature with some addition information. However, both linear regression and tree-based algorithms failed in my case (the MAE is slightly worse).

An example is: Let's assume we have 3 types of surgeries with IDs X, Y and Z. One way to predict the lengths for future surgeries is to take the average of most recent 20 actual lengths of X, denoted as $\bar X$ and use $\bar X$ to predict a future case X. Similarly for Y and Z cases. Now I want to build a new ML model to beat the benchmark $\bar X$. My thought is to use $\bar X$ as a feature, combined with some other features like surgeon name, surgery difficulty level, etc to build a regression problem. I assume this model will at least outperform $\bar X$ since we have addition information (features) besides $\bar X$.

Is my thought "using the benchmark as a feature will most likely outperform the benchmark" correct? If so, any theory to explain why it failed. Some high-level ideas would be very helpful!

Comment: What do you mean by "using the benchmark as a feature will most likely outperform the benchmark"? Do you want to use Y to predict Y???!!!
What variables do you have?

Comment: @Mehdi See my new edits. Does it explain?

Comment: I don't think the Xbar helps you as the  it may be changed in future with more surgeries. You should include more features if possible such as years experience of the surgeon, the time of surgery (for example 9 for 9AM, 23 for 11PM), etc. Note than surgeon name (or ID) must be a categorical variable. However, I think this is a hard problem to model.

Comment: The length of a surgery may depend on many factors such as age of the patient, the experience of the surgeon which should be increased as he/she performs new operations, and so on. I don't know if you have access to such information.